# How does Masking work in the scaled_dot_product_attention of Language understanding Transformers?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I have been following Tensorflow's tutorial on Transformers for Language understanding. ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer)). However I'm a bit confused about Masks used in the function scaled_dot_product_attention. I know what are masks used for but I do know understand how they work in this function for example.

When I followed the tutorial I understood that the mask will have a matrix indicating which elements are padding elements ( value 1 in the masking matrix) and which are not ( value 0 in the masking matrix).
for example :

```
[0 , 0 , 1 
 1 , 0 , 0 
 0 , 1 , 0 ]
```

However I can see that the function  scaled_dot_product_attention tries to update the padded elements with a very large ( or small ) number which is -1e9 ( Negative 1 Billion ). This can be seen in the below line of the mentioned function :

```
      if mask is not None:
    scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)
```

Why is this done ? and how does this mathematically leads to ignoring these values ? . Below is the implementation shown in the tutorial :

```
   def scaled_dot_product_attention(q, k, v, mask):
  """Calculate the attention weights.
  q, k, v must have matching leading dimensions.
  k, v must have matching penultimate dimension, i.e.: seq_len_k = seq_len_v.
  The mask has different shapes depending on its type(padding or look ahead) 
  but it must be broadcastable for addition.

  Args:
    q: query shape == (..., seq_len_q, depth)
    k: key shape == (..., seq_len_k, depth)
    v: value shape == (..., seq_len_v, depth_v)
    mask: Float tensor with shape broadcastable 
          to (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k). Defaults to None.

  Returns:
    output, attention_weights
  """

  matmul_qk = tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True)  # (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k)

  # scale matmul_qk
  dk = tf.cast(tf.shape(k)[-1], tf.float32)
  scaled_attention_logits = matmul_qk / tf.math.sqrt(dk)

  # add the mask to the scaled tensor.
  if mask is not None:
    scaled_attention_logits += (mask * -1e9)  

  # softmax is normalized on the last axis (seq_len_k) so that the scores
  # add up to 1.
  attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_attention_logits, axis=-1)  # (..., seq_len_q, seq_len_k)

  output = tf.matmul(attention_weights, v)  # (..., seq_len_q, depth_v)

  return output, attention_weights
```

Comment: This  is a math question, not a programming question. The answer comes from an understanding of the softmax function. Because it’s not really about programming, I’m voting to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , so the value -1e9 resembles negative infinity. Therefor the softmax function will produce a probability of 0 to such elements and will be ignored when calculating the attention values.

Answer (score 0):

## UNIT TEST

scaled_dot_product_attention_test(scaled_dot_product_attention)
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 # UNIT TEST
----> 2 scaled_dot_product_attention_test(scaled_dot_product_attention)

/content/public_tests.py in scaled_dot_product_attention_test(target)
71     attention, weights = target(q, k, v, mask)
72
---> 73     assert np.allclose(weights, [[0.30719590187072754, 0.5064803957939148, 0.0, 0.18632373213768005],
74                                  [0.3836517333984375, 0.3836517333984375, 0.0, 0.2326965481042862],
75                                  [0.3836517333984375, 0.3836517333984375, 0.0, 0.2326965481042862]]), "Wrong masked weights"

AssertionError: Wrong masked weights